# How to get controls resizable correspondingly to screen resolution?

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, controls

Just faced with a following issue:
I've tried to resize my simpliest WPF app and noticed that controls are not responsive at all.

Note: I've tried symbiosis of various controls like **Grid**, **WievBox**, **Canvas** etc., to no avail.

here is XAML code, to be exact controls which I need to get resizable (responsive) correspondingly different resolutions (aspect ratios).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" MinHeight="768" MinWidth="1024" MaxHeight="1080" MaxWidth="1920" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
<Grid>
    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="576,278,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="559,518,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label"  FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="595,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="64"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button"  FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="720,427,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" Height="38"/>


</Grid>
```

**P.S.** Such writers as Nathan and McDonald in their books are broadcasting that WPF that's you need for adaptive and responsive application making. However, I'm in doubts after couple of days of looking for solution. I think WPF not much went ahead in contrast with Windows Form at least in terms of **adaptation** and **responsiveness** of applications.
So could someone help me in that matter.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are trying to work with WPF designer like you do with WinForms - that is your problem. Simple "drag-n-drop controls from toolbox to form" is not how we do it in WPF. Almost all time you just write a raw XAML and use designer just as preview window. It is much like building a HTML, and this is a key for **adaptation** and **responsiveness**. Anyway, there is an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Margin` to position controls, use your grid properties like `ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition` with things values like `Auto` and `*`

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

[Nice little tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/)

Answer (score -1):

Use *RowDefinition* and *ColumnDefiniton* for your Grid control instead of using *Margin* to place your controls. Also replace the Height and Width properties for the Ellipse and Rectangle with *Stretch*.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" MinHeight="768" MinWidth="1024" MaxHeight="1080" MaxWidth="1920" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >

 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Ellipse Grid.Row="0"
             Stretch="Fill"
             Stroke="Black" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1"
               Stretch="Fill"
               Stroke="Black" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2"
           x:Name="label"
           Content="Label"
           FontStretch="Normal"
           FontSize="24" />
    <Button Grid.Row="3"
            x:Name="button"
            Content="Button"
            FontSize="24" />
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Small]
[image: Big]

Comment: Isn't this answer looks exactly like one that was already posted by @TheGeneral?

Comment: @vasily.sib I was AFK for quite a bit and didn't see that there was an an answer already. No reason for downvoting.

Comment: First answer was here for 1.5 hours before yours, but ok, you where AFK. Anyway, isn't this answer looks exactly like one that was already posted by @TheGeneral?

Comment: @vasily.sib yes, TheGeneral's answer is correct but I guess it's just not complete. Pew also want to have responsive controls if I got it correctly? Therefor it's also important to remove the static heights and widths of the controls. I've updated my answer a few times. But yeah, I've could have written this as a comment as well.

Comment: there is a link in his answer with much more info

Comment: @dontbytime, thank you of course, However, I need all three controls in the single cell of the Grid. In other words, not for each control is to be a separate cell. I need single Grid cell and all the used controls  in that single cell must be adaptive  to resolution alteration.

Comment: @Pew Answer has been updated to one column. Does it fit now?

Comment: @dontbyteme. Due to horrible interface I have no clue how to add my piece of code here, for a better understanding what I need.

Comment: @Pew you can edit your first post and add your code there.

Answer (score -4):

Thanks guys, of course, however it's not a solution. See screens below.

[image: min resolution]
[image: max resolution]

As you can see , all important to me controls "swam" to left.

Comment: ~D-D-Double Post!

Comment: Who did invent such "useful" interfase. Dislike to him! There are lots of nice user-frindly forum engines!

Comment: If SO is too annoying for you, your are welcome on those _user-frindly forum_. By the way, there was a link on registration page - [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: you missed: user friendly interface forum. here's most horrible inteface I've ever seen. Just a mess.

Comment: well, this is primary opinion-based. SO is not a _forum_, it is _Q&A site_ and this is the best Q&A design of that I see.

Comment: tell me about that! it works like forum! Look at old good vBulletin engine at least. You'll get what's user-frindly inteface.

Comment: if you [take at tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - you will see, that _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites._ (see, this is not a forum, and not even close to vBulletin ofcourse)